# How can I run an Automate Selenium Test with Canopy F# in Safari and Edge?

Tags: selenium, safari, microsoft-edge, canopy-web-testing

I wrote a test in Visual Studio with Canopy and it works with Chrome and IE, but I need to do the same with Safari and Edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For these browsers the command to run the test is "start safari" in safari and "start edgeBETA" on edge. For a full list of all the browser start lines use this link [Canopy Documentation](https://lefthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/actions.html)